# Как расшифровывается let в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, терминология

Подскажите, как расшифровывается **let** в JavaScript?
Если с *var* и *const* понятно, то тут как-то не ясно.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916940/why-was-the-name-let-chosen-for-block-scoped-variable-declarations-in-javascri

Comment: [Тут](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/in-what-programming-language-did-let-first-appear) (особенно в комментариях к ответам) можно найти много интересного. :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что let значит "пусть" дословно?

Comment: "Пусть", "пускай", "положим", "допустим". "Let" как глагол, буквально, "позволять"/"допускать".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const расписаны все различия между let var const
а по значению слова - как в математике: "let x = 5 ~ пусть x = 5"

Comment: Спасибо! Различия я понимаю. Интересует происхождение самого ключевого слова.

Comment: Как в математике - "пусть x = 5"

Comment: @kleshenki добавьте это в ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

`let` - это математическое утверждение, принятое в ранних языках программирования как Basic.
Обычные переменные считаются мало абстрактными, а создатели языков хотели выделить более высокий уровень абстракции, где `let` означало переменную, которая может быть назначена, но не изменена, что позволяло компилятору легче искать ошибки.

JavaScript использует `var` со времён создания языка, поэтому просто нужно было другое ключевое слово и разработчик языка позаимствовал из других языков, которые используют `let` как что-то, что ближе к `var`.

Но в JavaScript `let` создаёт локальную переменную в определённой области блока кода.

Прошу исправить если был в чём-то не точен.

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917071/2881286

Comment: если переводишь ответ, стоит добавлять ссылку на него: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917071/2881286